# PySide QTreeview beginRemoveRows wrong index

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I am using `QTreeView`, connected to a proxy model `QSortFilterProxyModel`, that is connected to a model `QAbstractItemModel`.

I'm struggling with removing the current index's row. What happens instead is that it will always remove its sibling with the last row.

For example, if I want to remove B, it will remove C instead:

A

---- B

---- C

I think my input is right, so I don't know why it's removing the wrong index. Currently my code to remove a row looks like this:

```
index = tree_view.currentIndex() # Get the current index.

mapped_index = tree_view.proxy_model.mapToSource(tree_view.currentIndex()) # Get the proper index to work with.

tree_view.tree_model.beginRemoveRows(mapped_index.parent(), mapped_index.row(), mapped_index.row()) # Removes wrong index!

tree_view.tree_model.endRemoveRows()
```

Also trying to remove it this way yields the same result:

```
mapped_index = tree_view.proxy_model.mapToSource(tree_view.currentIndex())

tree_view.tree_model.rowsAboutToBeRemoved.emit(mapped_index.parent(), mapped_index.row(), mapped_index.row())

tree_view.tree_model.removeRow(mapped_index.row(), mapped_index.parent())

tree_view.tree_model.rowsRemoved.emit(mapped_index.parent(), mapped_index.row(), mapped_index.row())
```

Comment: `tree_view.tree_model.beginRemoveRows` should not do the actual removal of the data. Inside the model's `removeRows` method you should call `beginRemoveRows` _before_ removing the actual data element from the internal data structure, _then_ you should actually remove the data element from the internal data structure and _then_ you should call `endRemoveRows`. So either something is wrong with the pseudo-code you're showing or with your model's `removeRows` implementation.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, thanks for responding! Right now I don't have `removeRows` subclassed in my model, should I be doing that? I also updated my original post with another way I was trying to delete a row, would doing it this way be ok?

Comment: Bah, I'm an idiot. I subclassed my `QTreeModel.removeRows` and `TreeItem.removeChildren` and now it all works as expected. I used these as reference: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-editabletreemodel-treemodel-cpp.html http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-editabletreemodel-treeitem-cpp.html

Note for others, QTreeView doesn't magically manage your stuff :)